# Permanent direct access (GNU/Linux to Windows)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows Laptop. When I access the ubuntu shell I always get redirected to `/home/myusrname`, but I want to open ubuntu and get directly to `/mnt/c`.

I already changed the environment file in `/etc` from

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

to

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c"
```

but nothing changed any suggestions? 
Thank you guys

Comment: I guess you have to change user home directory to `/mnt/c` you can do it using: `sudo usermod -d /mnt/c username`

Answer (score 2):

## The problem

The `PATH` variable is about where to find executable files. You should revert that change. If you ever want to make a change to this variable, then to it to `~/.profile` Don't do anything as root (with `sudo`), until you know what you are doing.

You are trying to change your home directory. I would not recommend using your MS-Windows `C:` drive. Your home directory has many configuration files in it (same as what the registry is used for in MS). MS also does not support the same file permissions, so can cause problems.

## What to do

### Make links

You can make links from your home directory `/home/myusername`, so that you can easily access `/mnt/c`.

```
cd ~
ln -s -T /mnt/c c-drive #link to c drive
ln -s -T c-drive/User/me ms-home # link to home on MS

#link other special directories
rmdir 'My Documents' && ln -s -T 'ms-home/My Documents' 'My Documents'
rmdir 'My Pictures'  && ln -s -T 'ms-home/My Pictures'  'My Pictures'
rmdir 'My Music'     && ln -s -T 'ms-home/My Music'     'My Music'
rmdir 'My Video'     && ln -s -T 'ms-home/My Video'     'My Video'
rmdir 'Downloads'    && ln -s -T 'ms-home/Downloads'    'Downloads'
```

You will have to fix the MS-directory-paths

### Make it your home directory (I don't recommend this, it can break stuff)

> `sudo usermod -d /mnt/c username`

Comment: The cheap option: `HOME=/mnt/c; cd`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Where would you put that (To be persistent)? And not cause config-files to be fragmented.

Comment: In at the end of the initialization file for interactive shells, e.g. `~/.bashrc`. But yes, you would possibly upset other programs (as would changing your _actual_ home directory with `usermod`).

Comment: @Kusalananda if you change `$HOME` then you'll break commands such as `ssh` that expect to find `$HOME/.ssh/...`. I don't see a real benefit in `HOME=` vs `usermod`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your `HOME` directory and just want to `cd` to `/mnt/c`,
you could edit your `~/.profile` and add this to the end of the file:

```
if [ -d /mnt/c ]; then
  cd /mnt/c
fi
```

This changes the directory to `/mnt/c` if the directory exists when you open a new (login) shell.

Then exit the shell and start a new shell to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to you **/home/myusername/.bashrc** file:

```
test -d /mnt/c && cd /mnt/c
```